# Looking for RMaps SQLite format details

Tags: tiles, android, sqlite, format

Locus Maps and Rmaps Android maps support an offline sqlite Format called Rmaps. I am trying to find the format details and how its organized. I couldn't, is there any dependable documentation online?

Comment: I couldnt find any. I explore it a bit and compared it with other SQLite formats. Check the notes at http://thejeshgn.com/2014/06/12/tiled-map-storage-in-sqlite/

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this software, its so cool for this task:

http://www.the-thorns.org.uk/mapping/

This is the software for your needs.It converts the image into the right sqlite format that you can use with your locus appliocation.

Comment: Seems worth the $24 purchase price.